# 'npm install' is showing errors while setting up react app from already built files

Tags: reactjs, npm

I only have these project files and folders of my react app

[image]

while running the npm install command I am getting this error in the terminal.

[image]

Comment: When creating a new project, always download the node modules specific to that project. This will help you avoid such issues.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you move folders around. To fix it, delete the `node_modules` folder and then install again.